# Books for memory mechanism of nonlinear systems?

Tags: resource-recommendations, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, complex-systems

The description of [complex-systems](/questions/tagged/complex-systems) aka [dynamical-systems](/questions/tagged/dynamical-systems) says:

> In such systems, nonlinear interactions can lead to **memory** and feedback mechanisms, self-organized criticality, and chaotic behavior.

I've read *Strogatz, Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos* and *Melanie Mitchell, Complexity: A Guided Tour*, yet still being unaware of that phenomenon.

What books focus on memory mechanisms of dynamical systems?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Science-Hysteresis-3-set/dp/0124808743

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest systems found to display some sort of memory were probably those with [**hysteresis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis).

Another important example are systems with **time delay**, e.g., described by [delay differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation), which can model a variety of different systems, e.g., "in physiological studies, in ecology, in lasers, etc.": Lakshmanan & Senthilkumar's [Dynamics of Nonlinear Time-Delay Systems](https://books.google.de/books?id=nV5F0kMsqa4C&lpg=PA2&ots=Rjyps2jbP0&dq=delay%20dynamical%20system%20memory&pg=PA201#v=snippet&q=memory&f=false).

[Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_theory) also display memory effects, including hysteresis (see, e.g., Majdandzic et al [Multiple tipping points and optimal repairing in interacting networks](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms10850)), and have been used to model the [Information Processing Capacity of Dynamical Systems](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep00514), as well as, of course, the [brain](http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v17/n5/full/nn.3690.html).

I don't currently know of any book focused exclusively on memory mechanisms of dynamical systems. A search reveals Alonso-Sanz' [Discrete Systems with Memory](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8119) , which might be close to what you're looking for.